# PHP Explode String Into Multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have the following string: "1,3,4,7" which I need to explode into an Array in the following format:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'id' => 1
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 3
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 4
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 7
   ),
);
```

This seems to be causing me a lot more pain than I'd have thought. Can anyone kindly assist please?

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: i think explode and a loop of some sorts might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode): First you create an array with the values and than you map all these values to the format you need in a new array.

Something like:

```
$vals = "1,3,4,7";

$map = array_map(function($val) {
  return array('id' => $val);
}, explode(',', $vals));

var_dump($map);
```

[An example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/z2CxJR).

Comment: Well I was just waiting for OP to show some work and effort, so that we don't just do his work or mutate to a code writing service. (With my answer http://imgur.com/0ZKYVhU). But seems like everyone doesn't bother about such stuff. (At least you gave a good explanation with some good references)

Comment: @Rizier123 You are completely right. I was just testing with anonymous functions and php versions and this fitted my test case. Sorry :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and I really appreciate the assistance, but didn't think it was worth adding my own sloppy looping to confuse matters more than necessary. I had done my due diligence of searching for something that fitted the bill, but nothing quite matched.

Comment: @Rikkiebags It's always a good idea to show your efforts to avoid being seen as someone who just wants to have their problems solved by someone else. It will get more people involved; I agree with Rizier123 and normally don't answer questions with just specifications of in- and output. On the other hand, don't worry too much about it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, taken on board and genuinely appreciated. I shall elaborate further in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$myArray=explode(",","1,3,5,7");

$result=array();
foreach($myArray as $key=>$arr)
{
    $result[$key]['id']=$arr;

}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: run this and check please.

Comment: sorry my bad, i missed "," in explode

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you explode the string to get the values in an array. Then you iterate through the array and set the data as array to another array

```
$string = "1,2,3,4";
$array = explode(",", $string);
$data = array();
foreach($array as $arr){
    $data[] = array('id' => $arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thinking-outside-the-box technique that doesn't require a loop or iterated function calls.

Form a valid query string with the desired structure and parse it.  The empty `[]` syntax will generate the indexes automatically.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/401pR))

```
$vals = "1,3,4,7";
$queryString = 'a[][id]=' . str_replace(',', '&a[][id]=', $vals);
parse_str($queryString, $output);
var_export($output['a']);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '4',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '7',
  ),
)
```